# Exception thrown: write access violation error in Tries Implementation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, data-structures, tree, access-violation

I have been trying to implement Tries in Visual Studio 2017.
Also the dictionary file contains exact 1000 words so thats not an issue.
Also the no of alphabets are 26 defined.
And i get errors on sometimes this line

`if (!temp->child[index])`
"Exception thrown at 0x000F8922 in ConsoleApplication23.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDFD"

or on this line

`temp->isEndOfTheWord = true;`

"Exception thrown: write access violation. temp was 0xFDFDFDFD"

```
struct TrieNode
{

TrieNode* child[No_Of_Alphabets];
bool isEndOfTheWord;
};

class Tries
{

 public:

TrieNode* getNode()
{
    TrieNode *parent = new TrieNode;
    parent->isEndOfTheWord = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < No_Of_Alphabets; i++)
        parent->child[i] = NULL;
    return parent;
}

void insertion(TrieNode* root, string word)
{
    TrieNode *temp = new TrieNode;
    temp = root;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
        int index = word[i] - 'a';
        if (!temp->child[index])
            temp->child[index] = getNode();
        temp = temp->child[index];
    }
    temp->isEndOfTheWord = true;
}

bool search(TrieNode* root, string word)
{
    TrieNode *temp = new TrieNode;
    temp = root;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
        int index = word[i] - 'a';
        if (!temp->child[index])
            return false;
        temp = temp->child[index];
    }
    return(temp != NULL && temp->isEndOfTheWord);
}
};

void main()

{

Tries T;
TrieNode* root = new TrieNode;
root = T.getNode();

string array[1000] = {};
ifstream dict;
dict.open("Dictionary.txt");
int x = 0;
while (!dict.eof())
{
    dict >> array[x++];
}
dict.close();

for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
{
    T.insertion(root, array[j]);
}

int choice = 0, z = 1;
string user_string;
cout << "TRIES IMPLEMENTATION\n\n";
while (z != 0)
{
    cout << "1-Insert A Word\n2-Search A Word\n3-Print All Words\n4-Exit\n";
    cout << "With which option would you like to proceed: ";
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "What is the word you like to add in tries: ";
        cin >> user_string;
        T.insertion(root, user_string);
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "What word would you like to search: ";
        cin >> user_string;
        if (T.search(root, user_string))
            cout << "Word searched found in Tries.\n";
        else
            cout << "Word searched was not found in Tries.\n";
        break;
//  case 3:
//      cout << "Printing all words:\n";

//      break;
    case 4:
        z = 0;
    }
}
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `TrieNode* root = new TrieNode;
root = T.getNode();` Memory Leak.

Comment: @GauravSehgal but the compiler isnt pointing to the code you are pointing to as a memory leak but to the ones in function "insertion" as mentioned in he post